# Check my proof on showing a graph with each vertex's degree at least $e$ has every tree with $e$ edges a subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Let $T$ be a tree with $e$ edges and $G$ be a simple graph such that ech vertex has degree at least $e$. We need to show that $T$ is a subgraph of $G$.

I tried to prove this by induction.

The base case is trivial.

The induction hypothesis says that for a tree with $e-1$ edges and a simple graph such that each vertex has degree at least $e-1$, then the graph has the tree as a subgraph.

If we add another edge to every single vertex of the graph, then there exists a tree with $e$ edges as a subgraph of the graph since there is already a tree with $e-1$ edges as a subgraph; after we added an edge to every vertex of the graph, the tree with $e$ edges is automatically a subgraph of the graph.

I am not sure whether my proof is correct. If there is something wrong, how could I fix it? Also, is there a better way to improve the writing of the proof?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with Hagen that you have the right idea. It is a serious logical error you made concerning induction, and I encourage you to read and fully grasp https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10034/1550 before attempting induction problems. After you read that then read my answer.

I give you any tree $T$ and graph $G$ such that every vertex in $G$ has degree at least $e$ where $e$ is the number of edges in $T$. Your task is to show me how to embed $T$ into $G$. How would you do it? To use induction means that you try to reduce your task to a smaller one. What would "smaller task" mean here? That's really up to you, as long as you consistently use the same measure, and you make sure that breaking tasks into smaller one always ends with bits that you can solve directly. One way here would be to use $e$ as the measure of task size, and clearly once $e$ gets down to $0$ you're done. So you notice that if you chop off a leaf from $T$ you get a tree $T'$ with one less edge, and embedding $T'$ into $G$ is a smaller task and hence can be done (by induction). Using the embedding of $T'$ into $G$, can you now see how to embed $T$ into $G$?

Comment: Well, the "right idea" I referred to was induction on $e$ (which you suggest as well). Why disagree with a little encouragement?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Hmm I do highly value giving encouragement, but in this case I felt that the proposed proof was totally off, and precisely because the asker didn't really understand induction, which most probably isn't his/her fault. I've seen so many **teachers** teach it wrongly, especially at the high-school level but also at university level, which is the main problem. I'm sure that once the asker grasps the proper meaning (not usage) of induction, the usage will not only be natural but also there will be no more such obvious logical errors.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for the help and yes I get your idea of smaller task. Just want to clarify that to embed $T$ into $G$, we add one more edge? I am not sure though.

Comment: @user338393: Add where? How exactly do you use the embedding of $T'$ into $G$?

Comment: @user338393: Drawing a vague diagram might help. For example, draw a blob representing G and a blob representing how $T'$ is embedded into $G$. Now $T$ has an extra edge so it must stick out from some vertex in the embedded $T'$. If you can figure out how to assign that extra edge to an edge in $G$ that isn't already used in the embedded $T'$ then you're done.

Comment: @user21820 I guess maybe we can add to a leaf in $T'$ since $T'$ has at least one leaf and it is possible because every vertex of $G$ has at least $e$ edges. Is it correct?

Comment: @user338393: Your second part is correct, but your first part is not. As I said, your goal is to embed $T$ into $G$. What $T'$ is is irrelevant unless it helps you achieve your goal. The way you obtained $T'$ was to chop off a leaf **from $T$**; you don't have any control over where that leaf is. Similarly you've no control over where you need to add back an edge to $T'$ in order to get back $T$. That is why you need **every** vertex in $G$ to have degree at least $e$.

Comment: @user338393: Think carefully through again; you hope to be able to use the solution to the smaller case, namely embedding $T'$ into $G$. But that embedding is not under your control (did you read my linked post?); it's under **mine**. No matter what embedding I give you of $T'$ into $G$, you must be able to use it to produce an embedding of $T$ into $G$. You've no control over where $T'$ is embedded into $G$, hence including where that extra edge needs to be attached to give you an embedding of $T$ into $G$.

Comment: @user338393: It just so happens that no matter which vertex $v$ you need to attach the extra edge to the embedded $T'$, there are enough edges in $G$ incident to $v$, and hence at least one edge isn't already used in the embedded $T'$.

Comment: @user21820 Yes I have read your linked post. And I get roughly what you are trying to say. Is it correct if I reason as follow: Since $T'$ has $e-1$ edges than the degree of each vertex of $T'$ is at most $e-1$. There are enough edges in $G$ incident to $v$ because each vertex of $G$ has degree at least $e$.

Comment: @user338393: Correct. Sorry for the delay in my reply as I was away. Always remember that an inductive proof is essentially a recursive verification procedure, so you always have to break down the object into smaller pieces (top-down). What you originally did in your question is a common mistake, which only shows that any tree with $e-1$ edges can be extended to a tree with $e$ edges that can be embedded into $G$, and does not show that **every** tree with $e$ edges can. Hope it's clear to you now! If you need a formal proof tell me and I'll add it.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for your reply. Yes I realised my mistake and thanks for the insight on induction. Induction on graph is indeed slightly tricky. I think I can write the proof already. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user338393: You're very welcome. You can upvote and/or accept answers to indicate if you're helped/satisfied by them.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but you should not modify $G$, esp.  you cannot expect to obtain a given degree-$e$ graph from an unspecified degree-$(e-1)$ graph. Instead try the following:

Let $T=(V_T,E_T)$ be a tree with $|E_T|=e$ edges (and hence $|V_T|=e+1$ vertices) and let $G=(V_G,E_G)$ be a non-empty, simple graph be given such that  all vertices of $G$ have degree $\ge e$. The case $e=0$ is trivial. If $e>0$ then $T$ has at least one leaf $v$. Let $w$ be $v$'s only neighbour. We remove the edge $vw$ and the vertex $v$ from $T$, obtaining a graph $T'=(V_{T'}:=V_T\setminus\{v\}, E_{T'}:=E_T\setminus\{vw\})$ which is a tree with $e-1$ edges (and so $e$ vertices). As in our given $G$, all vertices also have degree $\ge e-1$, we may use the induction hypotheses to embed $T'$ into $G$. That is, there exists an injective map $f\colon V_{T'}\to V_G$ such that $f(x)f(y)\in E_G$ whenever $xy\in E_{T'}$. 
The vertex $f(w)$  has at least $e$ neighbours. At most $e-1$ of these can be in the image of $f$ (because $|V_{T'}\setminus\{w\}|<e$).
Hence let $u$ be a neighbour of $f(w)$ not in the image of $f$.
Now define $g\colon V_T\to V_G$ as $$g(x)=\begin{cases}u&\text{if }x=v\\f(x)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
We verify that $g$ is injective and that $g(x)g(y)\in E_G$ whenever $xy\in E_T$.

Comment: Thanks Hagen. But can you clarify what do you mean by image of $v$ (and $vw$)? Which map are you referring to? You didn't seem to have mentioned that.

Comment: @user338393 The map $T'\to G$ from the embedding we have from the induction hypothesis

Comment: I think there is another thing that I am still doubtful about. I agree with the statement that the vertex $f(w)$ has at least $e$ neighbours. But I am not sure about why there are at most $e-1$ of these vertices can be in the image of $f$? Also when you say $V_{T'}=V_{T}\setminus\{v\}$, is it automatic that $w\notin\{V_{T'}\}$? Then why do you still have to write $V_{T'}\setminus\{w\}$? Thanks